# MAP VIEW IN ANDROID - JUST SHOWING TILES. LIVE MAP VIEW IS NOT THERE

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, maps

i tried getting my location on the map by the following code but i am not getting the live map view..... only tiles grids etc...map view is not visible.. please see the code and help.

AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.java

```
package com.androidhive.dashboard;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidhive.dashboard.R;

public class AndroidGPSTrackingActivity extends MapActivity {

Button btnShowLocation;
MapView mapView;

List<Overlay> mapOverlays;

AddItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay;

GeoPoint geoPoint;
// Map controllers
MapController mc;

double latitude;
double longitude;
OverlayItem overlayitem;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_view);


    GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this);
    latitude = gps.getLatitude();
    longitude = gps.getLongitude();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();

    // Geopoint to place on map
    geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (latitude * 1E6),
            (int) (longitude * 1E6));

    // Drawable marker icon
    Drawable drawable_user = this.getResources()
            .getDrawable(R.drawable.mark_red);

    itemizedOverlay = new AddItemizedOverlay(drawable_user, this);

    // Map overlay item
    overlayitem = new OverlayItem(geoPoint, "Your Location",
            "That is you!");

    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);

    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
    itemizedOverlay.populateNow();
    mc = mapView.getController();
    mc.animateTo(geoPoint);
    mapView.postInvalidate();


        }

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

}
```

$

additemmizedOverlay.java

```
package com.androidhive.dashboard;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

/**
 * Class used to place marker or any overlay items on Map
 * */
public class AddItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

   private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mapOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

   private Context context;

   public AddItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
   }

   public AddItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
        this(defaultMarker);
        this.context = context;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView)
   {   

       if (event.getAction() == 1) {
           GeoPoint geopoint = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(
               (int) event.getX(),
               (int) event.getY());
           // latitude
           double lat = geopoint.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6;
           // longitude
           double lon = geopoint.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6;
           Toast.makeText(context, "Lat: " + lat + ", Lon: "+lon, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
       return false;
   } 

   @Override
   protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
      return mapOverlays.get(i);
   }

   @Override
   public int size() {
      return mapOverlays.size();
   }

   @Override
   protected boolean onTap(int index) {
       OverlayItem item = mapOverlays.get(index);
       AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.context);
       dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
       dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
       dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }
    });
       dialog.show();
       return true;
     }

   public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
      mapOverlays.add(overlay);
   }

   public void populateNow(){
       this.populate();
   }

}
```

map_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mapView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:enabled="true"
android:apiKey="API_KEY"
/>
```

$

Answer (score 0):

Android API v1 is deprecated and you can't have a new API key generated for it. You have probably generated one for API v2.

The easiest way to migrate to v2 is to remove all the code you have now and follow this link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start